# Add an element to a Rails will_paginate collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have a `Location` model that `has_many` `LocationPhotos`. The `Location` also `belongs_to` a single `LocationPhoto` as the `featured_location_photo`. The `belongs_to` association looks like this:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :featured_location_photo, class_name: 'LocationPhoto', foreign_key: 'featured_location_photo_id'
end
```

Using will_paginate, I can paginate the photos for a location like this:

```
location.location_photos.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 4)
```

Ideally, I would like to always include the `featured_location_photo` as the first element, on the first page, of the collection that's returned, and not be included again. So, for example, if the related photos have ids 1,2,3,4,5,6 and the featured photo has id 3, I would want page one to show photos with ids:

3, 1, 2, 4

And page two to show photos with ids:

5, 6

The collection should also show `total_entries` equal to 6.

Is there any way to do this? I can't think of a way to do it by scoping the query because there's no way to tell the featured photo to sort to the top of the results.

My other thought is to first check if the location has a featured photo. If it does, remove that from the query with a scope:

```
result = location.location_photos.where.not(id: [featured_photo_id]).paginate(page: 1, per_page: 4)
```

Then, I would need to add the featured photo back into the front of `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm totally saving this, because I've needed to solve this problem before and always copped out on the solution. Thanks for making me find this!!!

To promote a specific record in a collection use:

```
order("case when id = #{id} then 0 else id end")
```

Which means you can just create a custom scope like so:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  def photos
    location_photos.
      order("case when id = #{featured_location_photo_id} then 0 else id end")
  end
end
```

**EDIT:** actually, ActiveRecord relations respond to `unshift` just like arrays. So all you actually need is this:

```
def photos
  location_photos.unshift( featured_location_photo )
end
```

Which of course you can then paginate.

Comment: I'm confused. Was your answer originally completely different than this? I just spent an hour refactoring code to use your other solution (the case statement in the order clause), which worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for. I came back to accept your answer, and it's gone! This new solution you propose doesn't really accomplish what I need. Am I losing my mind?

Comment: It was, I updated it because I thought this did the exact same thing without messing with any other sorting you may have had going on. The case statement was explicitly ordering things by the ID column, but if you were sorting by date or another column it would override that. Does this not move the `featured_location_photo` to the start of the collection for you? I rolled my answer back for you :P

Comment: Based on my testing, when I use `unshift`, it adds the featured_location_photo to the front of the collection, but it doesn't remove the existing one, right? If so, then no it does not 'move' it as I would like. Also, you say "which of course, you can then paginate", but I don't think that's true. `unshift` returns an array, which will not respond to `paginate`.

Comment: As far your concern about the case statement suggestion, form what I can tell, it doesn't actually override other order methods, it just adds it to the query. I'm calling it chained with other order-related scopes, and they all just get included separated by commas: `ORDER BY case when location_photos.id = 4 then 0 else location_photos.id end, location_location_photos.upvotes - location_location_photos.downvotes DESC, location_location_photos.upvotes + location_location_photos.downvotes DESC, location_location_photos.id ASC`

Comment: Ahhhh, my bad. I guess I got ahead of myself and didn't look closely enough at the results! Does the case statement work the same combined with the other order related scopes even if the order you chain them together changes?

Comment: Nope, they have to be chained in the correct order. If the case statement scope was last, it would be at the end of the `ORDER BY` clause, which would not give me what I need. I was looking for some way to prepend a scope (besides setting a `default_scope`), but haven't found anything yet. So, for now, I'll just have to remember to do things in the right order. If you have any other suggestions, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could improve your models by removing the dual association and adding a column on the `location photo` model named `featured`.
This way you can have more than one featured photo for each location (eventually in the future this may be needed).
After that you can use:

`location.location_photos.order(:featured).paginate(page: 1, per_page: 4)`

And that would do the trick.

NOTE: I am aware that adding a column would cause most of the images to have an empty field on the table, but space is not a problem nowadays.

Comment: This is a great suggestion, I really appreciate it. At the moment, I am not in a position to make that sort of change.

Comment: Thanks for the :+1: though I couldn't resolve your issue. Regards ^_^